# Lucene QueryParser needed that works with Custom Analyzer having stopfilter and porterstemfilter

Tags: java, lucene

With QueryParser, the stemfilter does not seem to work and with AnalyzingQueryParser, the stop filter is not effective.

Is my observation correct?
How to solve this problem?

**Update**
OK So did some experiments with the code. The AnalyzingQueryParser does not allow stopfilter  and the QueryParser does not allow porterstemmerfilter with fuzzysearches.

So I need a QueryParser that allows fuzzy searches along with support for porterstemfilter and stopfilter.

Comment: If anyone has a different opinion about this, then please say so.

Comment: I havn't worked with lucene for some time, but I do remember that you need to use the same analyzers for both indexing and searching. Could this be the problem?

Comment: more information please. how did you come to the conclusion that things aren't working/effective?

Answer (score 0):

You can override extend the QueryParser by subclassing it if need be. I was able to use the StopAnalyzer with AnalyzingQueryParser without problems:

```java
Analyzer analyzer1 = new StopAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30, ImmutableSet.of("foo", "bar", "blop"));
QueryParser qp = new AnalyzingQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_30, "field", analyzer1);
Query q = qp.parse("foobar foo bar blop hello");
System.out.println("query  " + q);

q = qp.parse("foobar~ foo~ bar~ hell~");
System.out.println("query  " + q);
```

Create the query: field:foobar field:hello and field:foobar~0.5 hell~0.5 . This is lucene 3.0.3, so I'm not sure if this applies to your question back then. Anyway, I stumbled upon this and hoped it might help. You might run into problems with the stemmers if they add wildcard queries, in which case you might want to override the methods:

```java
@Override
protected Query getFuzzyQuery(String field, String termStr, float minSimilarity) throws ParseException {
    return super.getFuzzyQuery(field, termStr, minSimilarity);
}

@Override
protected Query getWildcardQuery(String field, String termStr) throws ParseException {
    return super.getWildcardQuery(field, termStr);
}
```